# ¿Cómo aplicar un estilo (@RowStyle) a un rango de filas (u otra condición compleja) en OpenXava?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, openxava

Entiendo que @RowStyle puedo condicionar a valores específicos de algún atributo.
Pero, ¿cómo puedo hacer cuando necesito diferenciar los primeros 5 registros (id >= 1 and id <= 5) de los demás registros?

Por ejemplo, cuando una entidad Actividad ya viene con 5 actividades por defecto.
La idea es mostrar los primeros 5 con algún color distintivo y los demas registros que vaya ingresando el usuaro final se muestren de forma normal. Así:

[image: Lista con los 5 primeros registros resaltados]

¿Cómo puedo aplicar el estilo únicamente a las 5 primeras filas?

Answer (score 0):

@RowStyle no permite definir una lógica compleja, sino únicamente compara con el valor de una propiedad. Sin embargo, con un poco de ingenio y gracia podemos conseguirlo. Simplemente haz que esa propiedad sea una propiedad calculada donde pongas tu lógica. Algo así:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.openxava.annotations.*;
import lombok.*;

@Tab(
    rowStyles={
        @RowStyle(style="row-highlight", property="tipo", value="defecto"),
        @RowStyle(style="row-red", property="tipo", value="extra")
    }
)
public class Actividad {

    @Id
    int id;
    
    @Column(length=50) @Required
    String description;

    public enum Tipo { DEFECTO, NORMAL, EXTRA };
    public Tipo getTipo() {
        if (id >= 1 && id <= 10) return Tipo.DEFECTO;
        if (id > 100) return Tipo.EXTRA;
        return Tipo.NORMAL;
    }

}
```

Fíjate en la propiedad tipo donde ponemos la lógica que determina el estilo.